# Button Onclick event and backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I current have an html file with the following:

```
<div class="button1">

    <button class="first" id="up" onclick="tranistionUp">
       Go Up
    </button>

    <button class="last" id="down" onclick="tranistionDown">
       Go Down
    </button>
</div>
```

I have the following in a backbone.js view file:

```
var BlahView = BackBone.View.extend({
  initialize:function(){},
  blah...
  blah...
 transitionUp: function(){
    blah...
 },
 tranistionDown: function(){
},
render:function (){
    blah....
}; 
});
```

When I click on the buttons I am seeing an undefined function error for both functions, I am new to backbone any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 25):

You're supposed to setup your event handlers in your `Backbone.View`.

HTML (added `id="myButtons"` to container `div`)

```
<div class="button1" id="myButtons">
  <button class="first" class="button-up">Go Up</button>
  <button class="last" class="button-down">Go Down</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript (added `events`)

```
var BlahView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click .button-up": "transitionUp",
    "click .button-down": "tranistionDown",
  },

  transitionUp: function() {
    console.log("Transition up");
  },

  tranistionDown: function() {
    console.log("Transition down")
  }

});

var blahView = new BlahView({ el: $('#myButtons') });
```

By specifying `onclick` attributes, your browser is expecting functions called `transitionUp` and `transitionDown` in the global scope. Your methods are defined in an object. Binding event handlers with HTML attributes is generally discouraged, especially if you're using Backbone (since you can't easily bind events to specific instances of your views).

Comment: Should be var BlahView = Backbone.View.extend({  its one word leading caps only